# Laravel 5 - Add a stylesheet only if on a certain page/controller (page specific asset)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My Laravel layout is currently as follows (removed navbar etc..):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' 
    type='text/css'>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        @yield('content')

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/toastr/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I attach a view to the layout:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

Content here.

@endsection
```

I'm confused as to, say for example, if I'm in the `clinicController.php` or within a clinic route (it's a resource), then to "inject" a stylesheet and a Javascript file into the appropriate places.

Is there a way to do this? I'd imagine that `@if on a certain page, display this` would work, but I'm sure there must be a more "Laravel" way to do it?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may create a `section` like the following in your `view`, for example:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/custom-style.css')}}" />
@stop
```

Then also in your `layout`, `@yield` that, for example:

```
<!--Static StyleSheets-->
<link href="{{asset('assets/css/common-style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Dynamic StyleSheets added from a view would be pasted here-->
@yield('styles')
```

Same goes for `script` tags, for example (A `layout` may look like this with `styles` / `scripts`):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Static StyleSheets-->
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/common-style.css')}}" />

        <!--Dynamic StyleSheets added from a view would be pasted here-->
        @yield('styles')
    </head/>

    <!-- Template Body -->
    <body>
        <!-- Other HTML Elements -->
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <!-- Dump all dynamic scripts into template -->
        @yield('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update**: Since Laravel 5.2, it's possible to use [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks) for `styles`/`scripts`, for example:

In A View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <!-- Content -->
@endsection

<!-- Push a style dynamically from a view -->
@push('styles')
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/common-style.css')}}" />
@endpush

<!-- Push a script dynamically from a view -->
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

The Template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Static StyleSheets-->
        <link href="{{asset('assets/css/common-style.css')}}" />

        <!--Dynamic StyleSheets added from a view would be pasted here-->
        @stack('styles')
    </head/>
    <!-- Template Body -->
    <body>

        <!-- Other HTML Elements -->
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        <!-- Dump all dynamic scripts into template -->
        @stack('scripts')

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im currently having the exact same difficulty understanding this. So exactly is the entry point for the example The Alpha had on top?

Comment: Would you go like View::make(layout.master) and put the js, css, and content sections there?

Comment: Its good this question is not 'protected' as I just cannot help myself: "thanks!", "me too!" ;) Nice, to the point answer.

Comment: Why did you use in the last example `stack`? If you only use it to push a single script or css, then you could just keep `yield`, right?

Comment: @Adam That's because Laravel gave that option later but earlier I used to use the approach you mentioned here :-)

Comment: I see that Laraval gave that option later, but why did you use it later? What is the benefit here of using `stack`?

Comment: @Adam, staying with the convention used in the tool/community so it'll be easier for everyone to stay synced. Just staying on the same page.

Answer (score 7):

If you are like me and do not like the idea of littering the scripts in multiple view files, you can do it in a maintainable fashion in your template using any one of the following:

**If Using Named Routes**

```
@if (in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['profile', 'register']))
    <script src="example.js"></script>
@endif
```

**OR** (Same as above)

```
@if (in_array(\Request::route()->getName(), ['profile', 'register']))
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <script src="another.js"></script>
@endif
```

**To Check For Controller Actions Instead**

```
  @if (in_array(substr(Route::currentRouteAction(), strpos(Route::currentRouteAction(), '@')+1), ['create', 'edit']))
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  @endif
```

**To Specify a Controller And an Action**

```
  @if (in_array(substr(Route::currentRouteAction(), strpos(Route::currentRouteAction(), 'Controllers')+12), ['UserController@create', 'AlbumController@edit']))
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  @endif
```