# Dynamically Load Chunks Based on Route in a Laravel Application

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I'm writing an app using Laravel that requires different javascript on each page.  So, I decided to use Webpack to split the code on a page-by-page basis.  For example I have a one chunk for code relating to `mywebsite.com` and another chunk for code relating to `mywebsite.com/members/new` and an `app.js` for the common modules.

What would be the best way to dynamically require these files based on the url?

Comment: Add js files per view, not url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an if statement in your view template like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44250417/2311074):

```
@if (in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['profile', 'register']))
    <script src="example.js"></script>
@endif
```