# Load specific scss file for certain pages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sass

So my question is on the title. I found several answers to include CSS files on a certain page on SO like [Laravel 5 - Add a stylesheet only if on a certain page/controller (page specific asset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716599/laravel-5-add-a-stylesheet-only-if-on-a-certain-page-controller-page-specific)

But is it possible to do it with a `.scss` file which would be then compiled and add as .css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `app.scss` file is defined in `webpack.mix.js`  file, similarly you can define your own custom scss and compile it to css and call it in any of the blade as per requirement.

In `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/sass/custom.scss', 'public/css');
```

`custom.scss` will get compiled to `custom.css` in `public/css` directory

You can call this file for any particular blade.

If you wish to include more `scss` files to `custom.scss`, then you can import it as shown below,

In `custom.scss`

```
@import '../assets/admin/css/dashmix.min.css';

@import '../assets/admin/css/xwork.min.scss';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well nice it will work perfectly for my project :) But do you think that's a good practice to update `webpack.mix.js` for each new custom .scss files that I create ?

Comment: If you want to load specific css file for particular blade file then this is the only option in my knowledge. I wish you should compile all scss file together and use it in single app.blade.php file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want a specific file to be loaded in a certain page. If so, try using this in your blade:

```
@section('styles')
    <link href="{{asset('assets/file-i-want-to-be-loaded.css')}}" />
@stop
```

Try looking at the "Compiling Assets" from Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix