# Do using if else condition in using external css and js in the main layout is better in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm just new to Laravel and Vuejs, I have this problem that my system loads very slow because of external css and js I used. I only have one layout where all of my external css and js are imported. Do using if else condition before the runtime is a good approach to prevent the loading of unused external css and js?
here is a sample code where these two external css only runs on a single page

```
  @if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==='/dashboard/inventory')
        <link href="{{ url('css/authenticated.css?d='. $date) }} " id="styles" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ url('css/template/style.css?d='. $date)}}" rel="stylesheet">
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a section 
like the following in your view, for example:

first go to your main page and create section in page

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('styles')
    <link href="{{ url('css/authenticated.css?d='. $date) }} " id="styles" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url('css/template/style.css?d='. $date)}}" rel="stylesheet">
@stop
```

Then also in your layout, @yield that, for example:

```
<!--Dynamic StyleSheets added from a view would be pasted here-->
```

`@yield('styles')`

Comment: here is answer your ques for more detail

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30716905/8863063

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#template-inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much! I just want to make things clear for me because I'm always worrying about the performance